# Is this statement about simple finite group true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have proven it by myself, so I'm not sure whether I proved it right or wrong.

That is:

> Let $G$ be a simple finite group.
>
> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $H\neq G$.
>
> Then, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{|G:H|}$.

Is this true?

Comment: Yes, it is...but it would be nice to see **your** proof.

Comment: I have come up with an explanation for your question, but I'm not sure if it will satisfy you. Do you think it is correct? </sarcasm> The correctness of the question statement does not guarantee the correctness of your proof. You are going to have to show the *proof* to see if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G acts on the left cosets of H by left multiplication. This provides a homomorphism from G to $S_{index[G:U]}$, the group of permutations on index[G:U] elements.

The kernel of this homomorphism is $Core_G(H):=\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$.

To see this note that:

$ker(\phi)=\{g\in G:gxH=xH$ $\forall x\in G \}=\{g\in G:x^{-1}gxH=H$ $\forall x\in G \}=\{g\in G:x^{-1}gx \in H$ $\forall x\in G \}=\{g\in G:g \in xHx^{-1}$ $\forall x\in G \}=Core_G(H)$

Now with the homomorphism theorem we obtain that:

$G/Core_{G}(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{[G:H]}$.

Finally we have to show that $Core_G(H)=\{e\}$ (Because $G/\{e\}\cong G$).

It just follows from the  fact that $Core_G(H)\subseteq H \neq G$ and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Let $m=(G:H)$. The action of cosets gives a group homomorphism $\phi\colon G\rightarrow S_m$. Since $G$ is simple there are only two choices for $\ker(\phi)$. Now consider these two cases.